# Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Tags: magento2

When I compile static with `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, I'm getting the following errors:

> Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'
>
> Unable to get content for 'frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/source/lib/_lib.less'

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. Then I went through the comments from different people on GitHub [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7994). After that I was able to fix by recovering the folder "lib/web/css" or whole "lib/web" under root directory.

Lastly run the command and there was no error :

> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f

Based on your setup version you can take it from here : https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.3/lib

Answer (score 0):

Your Magento probably was poorly updated, you might be able to fix it by getting a new composer installation in the same version and replacing your lib folder with a clean lib folder from the native installation.